# On the Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

Let's take the family of analytic one to one functions, $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ (with $G\neq \mathbb{C}$ a region and $z_0\in G$ a fixed point) such that $|f|<1$, $f(z_0)=0$ and $f'(z_0)$ is a real positive number.

One question is to find all the regions $G\neq \mathbb{C}$ such that the previous family is non empty. Clearly, thanks to the Riemann mapping thm, all the simply connected regions are one of those regions. However, I think we can have a bigger class of regions, like an annulus. Also I think that $\mathbb{C}$ minus one point can't be one of them, but I can't prove it yet.

Any help with this will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: If z_0 is a fixed point and f(z_0)=0, z_0=0?

Comment: @vvnitram no, $0$ may not belong to $G$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition on $f'(z_0)$ can be omitted, since $f$ is not one-to-one in a neighbourhood of a point where $f' = 0$, while if $f'(z_0) \ne 0$ you can always multiply $f$ by a constant of absolute value $1$ to make $f'(z_0)$ real and positive.

Since you can translate, and multiply by a positive constant, any bounded region qualifies.  So does any region that omits a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb C$, because you can invert and then multiply.
So does the complement of a line segment, e.g. for the complement of $[0,1]$ consider $1/(1+\sqrt{1/z-1}) + c$.

On the other hand, the complement of a finite set does not qualify, because each of the points in the complement would be a removable singularity, and when the singularities are removed you'd have a bounded entire function.