# Constructing an analytic function for non simple connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

This is strongly related with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734010/on-the-riemann-mapping-theorem), asked by me here a couple of days ago.

Thanks to the Riemann Mapping thm proof (for example L.V Ahlfors' proof), we know that if $G \neq \mathbb{C}$ is a simple connected region (and $z_0\in G$ is fixed), then there exist an injective analytic function $h:G\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $h(z_0)=0, \ h'(z_0)>0, |h|<1$ and
$$
h'(z_0)\geq f'(z_0)
$$
for any other injective analytic function $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ with $f(z_0)=0$ and  $ f'(z_0)>0$ and $|f|<1$. In fact this function $h$ is constructed by taking square roots, something that can be done since $G$ is simply connected.

However, it is easy to see that this function $h$ also exist for non simple connected regions (injective analytic functions $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ with $f(z_0)=0, \ f'(z_0)>0$ and $|f|<1$, **do** exist in some of those regions, see my previous question, and the closure of the family containing this functions is the family it self plus the $0$ function).

My question, is how can we construct the function $h$ in the non simple connected case? I have been able to do it for example for the annulus $\{0<|z|<R\}$ since it reduces to the simple connected case (for the origin must be a removable singularity). But I get in trouble taking the annulus $\{r<|z|<R\}$ with $0<r<R$, and worst with more complicated regions as $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

I will be very grateful with any help or hint given.

Comment: I don't get what is $f$ in the case of $G$ being an annulus : $f$ is supposed to be holomorphic and one-to-one $G \to \{|z| < 1\}$ ? then $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $ \{|z| < 1\}$ and $G$ is open and simply connected by the open mapping theorem ?

Comment: @user1952009 the problem here is that in the annulus case, $f$ is not onto hence the domain of $f^{-1}$ is not the unit disk.

Comment: that's what you wrote : one to one analytic function $f: G \to \{|z| < 1|\}$, hence you meant $f: G \to U \subset \{|z| < 1|\}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I am so sorry for that, I have made an edit fixing the issue. Any thoughts so far? Thanks for correction btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extremal function $h$ that you describe (which is unique, if normalized correctly) is closely related to the theory of conformal mappings of multiply connected domains onto canonical domains. Indeed, if $G$ is multiply connected, the map $h$ gives a conformal map of $G$ onto the unit disk minus circular radial slits.

For a proof, see Nehari's book *Conformal Mapping*, (36) Chap. VII p.352. Another good reference for the theory of conformal mappings of multiply connected domains is Goluzin's book *Geometric Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable*.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the references, they proved to be very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.